# Polly retry unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, xunit, polly

I am using polly to handle retry (see below code). How can I unit test polly retry? using xunit and moq

```
services.AddHttpClient("GitHub", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
})
.AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(builder => builder.WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
{
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
}));
```

Comment: I recommend looking up a library called [simmy](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Simmy) which allows you to set up chaos policies. These policies will allow you to set a percentage of how often a http request will cause a transient error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [retry polly unit testing (xunit and moq)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73087890/retry-polly-unit-testing-xunit-and-moq)

Comment: As I stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73096084/13268855) you can't unit test such code, since the retry policy is attached to the HttpClient via the DI. In case of unit testing you are not relying on your DI. This integration can be tested via an integration or component test.

Comment: Hi, There is a nice way to test these type of scenario using Http interceptions - using JustEat nuget, checkthis out -> https://github.com/justeat/httpclient-interception

if you polly retry policy is in a an extension method then add that policy to test code and you can assert it

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments I recommend [Simmy](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Simmy).

It allows you to inject exceptions, return `BadRequests` and etc. in order to trigger Polly's fault and resilience policies such as `WaitAndRetry`.

These are a few samples from the [documentation](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Simmy/blob/master/README.md).

**Inject (Socket) exception**

```
var chaosPolicy = MonkeyPolicy.InjectException(Action<InjectOutcomeOptions<Exception>>);
```

For example: it causes the policy to throw `SocketException` with a probability of 5% if enabled

```
var fault = new SocketException(errorCode: 10013);
var chaosPolicy = MonkeyPolicy.InjectException(with =>
    with.Fault(fault)
        .InjectionRate(0.05)
        .Enabled()
    );
```

**Inject (BadRequest) result**

```
var chaosPolicy = MonkeyPolicy.InjectResult(Action<InjectOutcomeOptions<TResult>>);
```

For example: it causes the policy to return a bad request HttpResponseMessage with a probability of 5% if enabled

```
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
var chaosPolicy = MonkeyPolicy.InjectResult<HttpResponseMessage>(with =>
    with.Result(result)
        .InjectionRate(0.05)
        .Enabled()
);
```

Simply set the `InjectionRate` to `1` to guarantee a fault in your unit test.

---

If you want to use the `InjectionRate` less than 1 you can use xunit and moq chaining via `SetupSequence` and `Moq.Language.ISetupSequentialResult`. Here's an example from an blockchain challenge I had to do, I execute 4 calls in a row, so if the InjectionRate is 0.25 one of the 4 calls would trigger a Polly policy:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Should_Return_GetEthereumTransactionsAsync()
{
    // Arrange
    IConfiguration settings = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
    IOptions<Settings> optionSettings = Options.Create(new Settings
    {
        CompanyKeyAPI = settings.GetSection("CompanyKeyAPI").Value,
        ProjectId = settings.GetSection("ProjectId").Value
    });

    var sequenceHttpResponse = new List<Tuple<HttpStatusCode, HttpContent>>
    {
        new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, HttpContent>(HttpStatusCode.OK, ApiCompanyKeyResponses.EthereumBlockWithTransactionHashs()),
        new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, HttpContent>(HttpStatusCode.OK, ApiCompanyKeyResponses.Transaction(1)),
        new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, HttpContent>(HttpStatusCode.OK, ApiCompanyKeyResponses.Transaction(2)),
        new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, HttpContent>(HttpStatusCode.OK, ApiCompanyKeyResponses.Transaction(3))
    };

    IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory = base.GetChainedCompanyKeyHttpClientFactory(new Uri(Path.Combine(optionSettings.Value.CompanyKeyAPI, optionSettings.Value.ProjectId)), sequenceHttpResponse);
    CompanyKeyService CompanyKeyService = new CompanyKeyService(httpClientFactory);

    // Act
    List<EthereumTransaction> ethereumTransactionsResult = CompanyKeyService.GetEthereumTransactionsAsync(blockNumber, address).Result;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsType<List<EthereumTransaction>>(ethereumTransactionsResult);
    Assert.NotNull(ethereumTransactionsResult);
    Assert.Equal(ethereumTransactionsResult.Count, 3);
    Assert.Equal(ethereumTransactionsResult[0].result.blockHash, blockHash);
}


public IHttpClientFactory GetChainedCompanyKeyHttpClientFactory(Uri uri, List<Tuple<HttpStatusCode, HttpContent>> httpReturns, HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Mock<HttpMessageHandler> httpMsgHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
    var handlerPart = httpMsgHandler.Protected().SetupSequence<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", new object[2]
    {
        ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
    });

    foreach (var httpResult in httpReturns)
    {
        handlerPart = AddReturnPart(handlerPart, httpResult.Item1, httpResult.Item2);
    }
    httpMsgHandler.Verify();

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpMsgHandler.Object)
    {
        BaseAddress = uri
    };
    Mock<IHttpClientFactory> clientFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
    clientFactory.Setup((IHttpClientFactory cf) => cf.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(client);
            
    return clientFactory.Object;
}

private Moq.Language.ISetupSequentialResult<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> AddReturnPart(Moq.Language.ISetupSequentialResult<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> handlerPart,
HttpStatusCode statusCode, HttpContent content)
    {
        return handlerPart

        // prepare the expected response of the mocked http call
        .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = statusCode, 
            Content = content
        });
    }
```

....

```
public class CompanyKeyService : ICompanyKeyService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    public CompanyKeyService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        _client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("GitHub");
    }

    public async Task<List<EthereumTransaction>> GetEthereumTransactionsAsync(string blockNumber, string address)
    {
        //Validation removed...
   
        List<string> transactionHashs = await GetEthereumTransactionHashsByBlockNumberAsync(blockNumber);
        if (transactionHashs == null) throw new Exception("Invalid entry. Please check the Block Number.");
        var tasks = transactionHashs.Select(hash => GetTransactionByHashAsync(hash, address));
        EthereumTransaction[] lists = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        return lists.Where(item => item != null).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please prefer `await` over `.Result`

Comment: According to my understanding in your provided sample you are making asserting only against the result. So, how does it test the integration between the HttpClient and the retry policy?

Answer (score -1):

You can unit test this by mocking out the HttpClient and setting up your own test version of the WaitAndRetryAsync policy.
Example:

```
var mockHttpClient = new Mock<HttpClient>();
var mockRetryPolicy = new Mock<IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>>();

mockRetryPolicy
    .Setup(p => p.ExecuteAsync(It.IsAny<Func<Context, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>>>(), It.IsAny<Context>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage());

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services
    .AddHttpClient("GitHub", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    })
    .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(builder => mockRetryPolicy.Object);

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("GitHub");

Assert.NotNull(httpClient);
```

Comment: This only tests that a mock is being called, not that the retry policy is working.

Comment: found this https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Unit-testing-with-Polly---with-examples

Comment: In your test you recreate an alternative HttpClient + retry integration. So, this code does not test any part of the original code.