# retry polly unit testing (xunit and moq)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I have .net core weabpi (see code below). I am using polly retry policy (see policy below). I would like to unit test endpoint (getProducts) and test polly retry

I have found [these examples](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Unit-testing-with-Polly---with-example) but it is not clear how to unit test endpoint and retry policy?

```
services
  .AddHttpClient<IProductService, ProductService>()
  .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy(3, 2)); 

static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy(int retryCount, int breakDuration)
{
    return HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(breakDuration,
            retryAttempt)));
}
```

**.Net core api:**

```
public interface IProductService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<ProductResponse>> GetProducts(string productType);
}
```

```
public class ProductService: IProductService
{ 
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    
    public ProductService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
         _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductResponse>> GetProducts(string productType)
    {
         var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("uri");
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you using productService in controller?

Comment: Could you describe your test case(s) with [Given When Then](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/GivenWhenThen.html) structure? Because *unit test endpoint and retry policy* does not tell anything about your testing intent.

Comment: Given= GetProducts is called, When it return error 5XX error Then retry 3 times

Comment: a workaround would be add an instance of the policy to DI container during startup and inject it into your service. Than you could `retryPolicy.Policy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await client.GetAsync("uri"))`. you could mock the http side to respond with http codes in a sequence , and capture the request bodies to test  that it posts as many times as you expect it to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update (02/21/24)**

In case of V8 you can make assertions against the strategies' options. In this Polly version the strategies behavior can be configures via `XYZStrategyOptions`. And gladly these objects are retrievable after you have created your pipeline.

[Here you can find the related documentation page](https://www.pollydocs.org/advanced/testing.html)

```
// Retrieve the descriptor.
ResiliencePipelineDescriptor descriptor = pipeline.GetPipelineDescriptor();

// Check the pipeline's composition with the descriptor.
Assert.Equal(2, descriptor.Strategies.Count);

// Verify the retry settings.
var retryOptions = Assert.IsType<RetryStrategyOptions>(descriptor.Strategies[0].Options);
Assert.Equal(4, retryOptions.MaxRetryAttempts);

// Confirm the timeout settings.
var timeoutOptions = Assert.IsType<TimeoutStrategyOptions>(descriptor.Strategies[1].Options);
Assert.Equal(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), timeoutOptions.Timeout);
```

---

The sad truth is you can't really unit test your retry+endpoint logic and here are my reasoning:

1. The retry is registered on the top of the `HttpClient` via the DI (`AddPolicyHandler`). When you are unit testing then you are **not relying** on the DI rather on individual components.
   1.1 So, an integration test might be more suitable for this. I've already detailed how can you do that via [WireMock.Net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net): [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68540520/13268855), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63049086/13268855). The basic idea is to create a local HTTP server (to mock the downstream system) with a predefined response sequence.
2. After you have defined your retry policy with the max retry count and time penalties, you can **not** retrieve them easily. So, from a unit testing perspective it is really hard to make sure that the policy has been defined correctly (like the delay is specified in *seconds*, not in *minutes*). <s>I've already created a [github issue for this](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/756), but unfortunately the development of the V8 got stuck.</s>

---

Back to your test case. The correct way to articulate your test scenario with the given-when-then structure should be written like this

- **Given** a faulty downstream service which returns 5XX responses
- **When** I call GetProducts
- **Then** it is performed 4 times (1 initial + 3 retry attempts)

This is not a unit test. It is more like a component/integration test. Why? Because even though [you could create an HttpClient mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425008/mocking-httpclient-in-unit-tests) but in that case there will be **no** retry policy there.

There is a workaround: you could [manually decorate the underlying handler with the policy via the `PolicyHttpMessageHandler`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73036620/13268855). But that's a bad idea in a unit test, because you basically re-implemented the DI part inside your test. And with that you would test your test arrangement code, not your production code.